# Why is "static" needed for a global const char but not for a bool?

Tags: c++, static, global-variables

Shared header.

I can do this:

`const bool kActivatePlayground=false;`

Works fine when included among multiple files.

I cannot do this:

`const char * kActivePlayground = "kiddiePool";`

Results in error: duplicate symbols.

But this works:

`static const char * kActivePlayground = "kiddiePool";`

Why is the `static` needed for the `const char *` but not for the `const bool` ?  Additionally, I thought `static` is not necessary since `const` is always `static` implicity?

Comment: static makes a symbol private to that TU. from the error, have you made sure there is no redefinition of the const char * in any other file?.

Comment: this is the only definition of the variable name

Comment: again, i re-iterate: `const` is implicitly `static` anyway, so the use of the word `static` shouldn't even be necessary, just as it isn't necessary for the `bool`

Comment: kActivePlayground is not `const`. hence it is not static. its a pointer to a const. static keyword make it, well, a static. declare and initialize it as so `char * const kActivePlayground = "whatever"`.

Comment: I can address the issue of `const` directly, but I'm still hunting in the standard for the reason `static` is required for your `char *`. In C++11 § 7.1.1p7, "A name declared in a namespace scope without a storage-class-specifier has external linkage unless it has internal linkage because of a previous declaration and provided it is not declared const. Objects declared const and not explicitly declared extern have internal linkage." I know that doesn't address your question about `char *`, but I'm still looking. Interesting question.

Comment: @Koushik has hit the nail on the head and should turn the comment into answer. this was a rookie mistake. The pointer itself was not set to `const` and hence was a duplicate symbol. the `const` was modifying what is pointed at, but did not modify the actual variable, in this case, the pointe.r

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In C++, `const` variables by default have static linkage, while non-`const` variables have external linkage.

The reason for the multiple definitions error is that

```
const char * kActivePlayground = "kiddiePool";
```

creates a variable with external linkage.

Hey wait, didn't I just say that `const` variables default to static linkage?  Yes I did.  But `kActivePlayground` is not `const`.  It is a non-`const` pointer to `const char`.

This will work as you expect:

```
const char * const kActivePlayground = "kiddiePool";
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I missed it too and was wracking my head trying to see how it didn't qualify as internal linkage (pouring over 3.5 repeated say wtf to myself). Nice answer.

Comment: Which is why I will argue (against English speakers) that `const` always ought to be at the *right* of what it qualifies, `const char*` may make you doubt but `char const*` will not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constant char array

```
const char kActivePlayground[] = "kiddiePool";
```

and kActivePlayground can also be used for assignment because it is a reference

```
const char* playground_text = kActivePlayground;
```